# 'i' meaning and why is it there?

Tags: c++, variables, declaration

I'm new here as well to coding. Recently I've been going through *Principles and Practice Using C++* and inside his code there is always an `i` inserted into his examples. Some are inside "vector's subscript" function, or inside "for statements" such as `int i.` But he didn't even make an int called `i`, it's just there. Maybe I missed something while reading, I don't know, but I hope someone wouldn't mind giving me a meaning as to why it's inserted in the places it's placed in, or just the meaning of `i`.

---

Below I took one of his examples from page 148 to show you

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> temps; //temperatures
    double temp = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double high_temp = 0;
    double low_temp = 0;

    while (cin>>temp) // read and put into temps
        temps.push_back(temp) ;

    for (int i = 0; i<temps.size(); ++i) // these 'i's
    {
        if(temps[i] > high_temp) high_temp = temps[i]; // and these
        if(temps[i] < low_temp) low_temp = temps[i];
        sum += temps[i]; // compute sum
    }

    cout << " High temperature: " << high_temp<< endl; // find high
    cout << " Low temperature: " << low_temp << endl; // find low
    cout << "Average temperature: " << sum/temps.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: 'He didn't make an int called i', what do you think this is `for (int i = 0;`? That's making an `int` called `i`. I'm sure this must be explained in the book somewhere, otherwise it's a very poor book.

Comment: `for (int i = 0;`isn't it declaring an `int` *i*?

Comment: code should be compilable. If you want, add comments to that line. Adding `***` like that is even worse because it's the same as the multiply and dereference operator, and also the pointer declaration

Comment: @john Thank you a lot for the reply. I must skimmed over that part, because I had no idea I could make an int inside statements. Thought it always had to be before writing the statement. Thank you again.

Comment: @Tommy, This is a special case because it stops `i` from existing outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a software program, each variable that you declare must have a meaning, must represent something.

This is also the case in the book fragment you just read, only that we are talking about arrays. As you know, arrays are a collection of values of the same value type. Because it's a **collection**, it means there are 1 **or more** values into that array.

This raises the question: *if there are 1 ore more values, how can I acces one specific value of that array?* Here is where the `i` you read comes in.

The variable `i` has the meaning of *the position of the array I am working on right now*, where "working on" can mean reading, writing, etc. Because `i` is a variable, it must have a data type, hence the `int i` notation.

Using `i` as a variable in this context is not mandatory, but it's a very common practice. If you have a matrix, for example, you will need two such variables (one for rows and one for columns) which most likely will be `i` and `j`.

This also explains why we use `i` inside a `for` loop. In English, this means that the loop works with the elements that have the coefficient number from 0 to the array size.

`i` was declared as an `int` type in the `for` loop, but it could also be declared before that loop. Something like:

```
int i=0;

...

for (i=0; i<...)
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is declared as a variable of type `int`, here:

```
for (int i = 0; .......)
{
   // 'i' used here
}
// 'i' cannot be used here
```

That `i` has a scope only inside that for loop. After the loop terminates, so does the lifetime of that variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a part of convention, where it stands for `iteration number`.

It has been defined in the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0 ....
```

Which basically states that you start from iteration number zero. Once you gain some experience, you will see that iterations don't always start from zero, so `i` may be initialized with a different value (or a different variable name may be used instead of `i` altogether).

Mathematically, `i` is often used in context of a list/array: `the ith element` or `summation from i=0 to i=n` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an integer, used as an `i`ndexing variable. You often see it in loops.

First, let's think about a vector and what it looks like. A vector is a variable-length array.

So if we have a `vector` named `myVector` with 5 elements, then we have something that looks like

```
myVector:   item1    item2    item3    item4    item5
```

Now how do we specify *individual items*? We'll need to index each item. Traditionally (from mathematics), indexing begins at 0. So to index the first element, we do `myVector[0]`. To index the second element, we do `myVector[1]`, and so on. (The `[]` is known as the *subscript* operator. You can also use `myVector.at(0)`, `myVector.at(1)`, but this is less used.)

Now what if we wanted to find the minimum or maximum value in a vector? We'd need to check each item and compare them. So we'll need to *iterate (loop) through the entire array*.

How do we do this? How do we iterate through **each** and **every** item? To loop through **each** item, we'd need something to specify the items. To loop through **every** item, we'd need a loop.

The loop in your code does this, iterating from 0 up to the length of the array/vector.

```
for (int i = 0; i < temps.size(); ++i)   // iterate through EVERY element of the vector
{
    //  access EACH element of using temps[i]
}
```